# How do I cast a function parameter to image?

Tags: javascript

I have a parameter in a function that is going to be an image. Now I want to make some checks with that object, like if it's undefined and if not what the source for the image in the object is.

Problem is though that I cant request `img.src` because the variable is just a un-typed parameter. I was thinking of creating a secondary `Image()`object, and then in some way solve it with `imgObject = img`, but that just looked silly and would probably not work.

So, how do I simply declare in the code that a parameter is of the type Image and that I want to request the specific Image type methods for that object?

Comment: I don't understand it. Please elaborate more. For now `var foo = new Image()` will create a new image object and put the reference to it into `foo`.

Comment: @jAndy thanks. Yea, I agree that the description looks pretty weak. I'll update it.

Comment: `param instanceof Image` might be useful, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language and you cannot say that what you are expecting is an image. However, you can do a manual check in the function code to see if the value is instanceof Image (Matt mentioned it above). On the other hand, you can try using typescript - but that works well only in VS though.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with variable typing. JavaScript does not have static types for variables, so the variable being "just an un-typed parameter" is a red herring. If the object is an image, you can treat it as an image. If treating it like an image isn't working, then the wrong thing is getting passed to your function and that's what you need to fix.

Comment: I believe you're absolutely right. I'm very new to Javascript, but I do have quite a bit of experience with Java, and I have a hard time distinguishing what separates them. I didn't see the `.source` pop up in the IDE as a possible method, so I just assumed that it had to be type casted. But of course it's down to the browser to be the judge of that rather than the IDE. I think I wrote this question a bit prematurely, so I'll vote to close it as soon as I've confirmed that my reason for the question wasn't a valid one.